# Least number of guesses needed to determine all unknown subsets of a set

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, graph-traversal

Say I have a set $\mathbb{S}=\{1,2,...,n\}$. I have an adversary who breaks up $\mathbb{S}$ into $k$ unknown and disjoint subsets. Denote this new set $\mathbb{A}$. I can guess any combination $s$ and my adversary has to tell me if $s$ is itself a *subset of any element* in $\mathbb{A}$.

For example, if $n=4$, a valid $\mathbb{A}$ might be $\{ \{2\}, \{1,3,4\}\}$. All "true" guesses are $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{4\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{3,4\}$, $\{1,4\}$, $\{1,3,4\}$.

What's the fastest algorithm and the upper bound on number of guesses I need to make to fully reverse engineer $\mathbb{A}$?

---

Obviously the brute force algorithm takes $^nC_1 + ^nC_2 + ... + ^nC_n $ guesses for every possible subset.

But I think I only need to test all possible subsets of size 2 i.e. exactly $^nC_2$ guesses?

Then, I can represent each of the correct guesses of size 2 as an undirected edge in a graph. Every member of $\mathbb{A}$ of size 3 or greater should form a simple cycle in this graph. So I just need to DFS on every node in this graph, removing the *longest* cycle detected from the graph, and repeat for all remaining nodes until only lone edges (subsets of size 2) or unconnected vertices (subsets of size 1) remain.

This graph should have $n$ vertices and at most $^nC_2$ edges. So the fastest algorithm has a time complexity of $\mathbb{o}(n^{2}\cdot{}^{n}C_{2})$. Is there an approach with fewer guesses or a faster graph algorithm?

**P.S.: In case anyone's interested about the context:** One example use case is if $n$ known services are hosted on unknown $k$ servers with unknown grouping, and you have some way to overload any subset of services to mount a denial attack on a server. The problem becomes if you can profile the servers with the least number of queries. I came across a similar scenario and thought this was a pretty interesting problem with no literature on.

Comment: When you say "subset of any subset" I think you mean "subset of any element".

Comment: @Draconis Yup, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: I bet you can do better than ask all pairs, especially since the number of parts is fixed. Also, the overall running time should be $O(n^2)$ or better.

Comment: "Every member of $\mathbb{A}$ of size 3 or greater should form a simple cycle in this graph" should be "Every member of $\mathbb{A}$ of size 3 or greater forms a connected component that is a complete graph.

Comment: So, it takes $O(n^2)$ to find all the components, as said by Yuval as well.

Comment: Good point on the connected component and runtime. Thanks both of you. Will mark the correct answer to anyone who can suggest a better strategy than $^nC_2$ guesses.

Comment: I am writing an algorithm that needs at most $O(n\log n)$ guesses.

Comment: There is a simple algorithm using $O(kn)$ queries. Find the part of 1 using $n-1$ queries. Then pick an element not in the part of 1, find its part, and so on.

Comment: I am trying to prove $\Theta(n^2)$ is the worst complexity of the number of guesses now.  Average  complexity of the number of guesses is probably $\Theta(n\log n)$, which might not be immediate to prove even if it is true.

Comment: @Katie, would you mark a proof that shows $\theta(n^2)$ is the worst complexity for the number of guesses for any algorithm as the correct answer?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Wow, appreciate the thought given to this. I had spent quite some time thinking about this so it's certainly nontrivial. Hmm, won't that be strictly worse than $^nC_2$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's a good strategy! I agree that works so it does improve on the bound if $k$ is known. I'm curious to see what Apass.Jack has in mind for $n \log n$ but will accept $\mathcal{O}(kn)$ if no one can beat that.

Comment: @Katie, there is a constant factor. For example, $\Theta(n^2)$ could be $\frac{n^2}9$.

Comment: There’s a simple $\Omega(n\log n)$ information-theoretic lower bound when $k$ is not fixed (or when $k=n/2$), by counting the number of possible partitions.

Comment: Here's an easy proof of $\Theta(n^2)$ worst-case time when $k$ is not fixed, or is $\Theta(n)$: Suppose $k=n-1$.  *Then there is exactly one edge in the graph.*  If you test fewer than $n(n-1)/2-1$ unordered vertex pairs, then there are at least two, say $ab$ and $cd$, that you haven't tested.  The input in which $ab$ is the only subset, and the input in which $cd$ is the only subset, therefore cannot be distinguished by any such algorithm.

Comment: It's too late to edit my previous comment, but please note that it applies only to algorithms that test only *pairs*.  An algorithm that tests at least some larger groups could conceivably do better.

Comment: @j_random_hacker In your example they still can't do better because testing anything bigger than a pair would result in *false*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple algorithm may be:

Loop on:

1. take the next unassigned element Ei and create a new set Si assigning Ei to it.
2. loop on all unassigned elements Ej, testing the pair {Ei,Ej}. If it is true, assign j it to Si.

In worst case, this is O(kn) as you won't do this loop more than k times. In average case, I am not sure...